# Why isn't an exception raised when dereferencing a null pointer in EL?

Tags: jsf, null, el

I have facelets' code like this:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{userCreationManager.user.creatorAspect.name}" />
```

Now I am quite sure that `creatorAspect` is `null` at the time the view is initially rendered. However I get no exception about this, and the `h:inputText` is rendered with an empty initial content. On post-back, I do get an error:

> Target Unreachable, 'creatorAspect' returned null

As expected. Why this discrepancy?